# Eytymology of the expression "Pissy Pants McGee."

Tags: meaning, etymology, expressions

What is the origin of the expression "Pissy Pants McGee"?
Thanks!

Comment: Is this an expression?

Comment: Did you try Wikipedia? I've never heard of this expression before. What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

I hesitate to call this an expression when it only gets [22 hits on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q="Pissy+Pants+McGee"). Apparently it was [said on an episode of Big Brother Canada 2](https://theboxrecaps.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/big-brother-canada-2-21-signs-youre-a-basic-bitch-april-23rd/), but it’s by no means a set phrase in the vernacular. It’s an ad-hoc formation that combines two elements:

1. **“pissy pants”** – a somewhat redundant though nicely alliterative extension of **[“pissy”](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/pissy)** (AmE slang) meaning “foul tempered; like a baby; whiny”
2. **“McGee”** – a generic sort of placeholder name with the primary function of being recognizable as a given name, as distinct from regular name-calling presumably in an attempt to lengthen and lend mock formality for humor