# Understanding of -pants vs. "pants" in UK speakers

Tags: word-usage, expressions, british-english

My wife, a native Spanish speaker, today asked me about why a youtuber would call themselves 'craftypants'.

I explained that -pants was added to something as synecdoche, so for example an intelligent person might be called a 'smarty-pants', a poor-humored person a 'grumpy-pants', *etc.*

However, I then realized that while this is common in the US, in the UK 'pants' by itself usually means what this Yank would call 'underwear', while what I call 'pants' would appear over there as 'trousers'.

How do such expressions as '[fancy-pants](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/537750/olden-pejorative-word-for-a-fancy-pants)' *sound* to speakers in the UK?  Are they understandable in meaning but recognizable as being North American?  Does putting a -pants ending on a word remove the association with intimate clothing?  Does it just sound bizarre?  Do parallel expressions like grumpy-trousers exist?  Are some combinations acceptable in polite speech, but others (*e.g.*, [pissy pants](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209373/eytymology-of-the-expression-pissy-pants-mcgee)) not?

**Edit**: There is much discussion in comments, and some in answers, about whether -pants is synecdoche.  That's fair, and I am happy to have the point challenged.  However, that's not my question.  Even if I am wrong, my question is how "-pants" sounds to UK speakers, and whether it is clear or not that it is *different* from "pants" (underwear).

Comment: Hang on:  as far as I know, 'pants' is the word for what the ancient Romans guarding Hadrian's Wall in Britannia called 'subligaria' (literally tied up leather covers for the soldier's unmentionables, worn under the military skirts), while in the USA it is the word for trousers.  That is why a Brit have to be careful not to say to an American friend that he plans to join him at the ball game in his check 'shorts'.

Comment: @Tuffy - But the question is about _pants_, not _shorts_! We _do_ use the word for an outer garment in some contexts - ski pants, harem pants, for example - so it doesn't sound _so_ odd to a British person.

Comment: I'm not sure this snowclone can be classed as involving synecdoche. Pants (however defined) are not an intrinsic part of a person, female or male. _Metonymy_ is broader.

Comment: "Fancy pants," in particular, seems like it could have originated in the UK - esp. considering their definition of "pants". Like: That person is so fancy - even their underwear is fancy.

Comment: I legitimately call my car Mr Gassypants and everyone (family and friends) all go along with it, including two very young half-sisters (aged 3 and 5) that picked it up immediately. I just liked the story of Mr Splashypants, particularly when Greenpeace then threw it back in the poll for the name of Boaty McBoatface ("we suffered a public vote mess, now you suffer it too!" kinda thing). I know what gassypants implies, and that's the effect I wanted. All of this is to say - we all naturally know the "-pants" ending in the UK.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It may not even be metonymy, as there is no requirement that something referred to as X-pants wear, or even be able to wear, pants. You can go to a fancy-pants restaurant or have a sassy-pants cat. I'd say it's not really metonymy or synecdoche when the reference word has no meaningful relationship to the referent.

Comment: Not all UK speakers use 'pants' to mean the undergarments. My wife from Lancashire and a large number of people in the north of England use the word to mean 'trousers'.

Comment: I once heard a male Mafia character in the US TV series _The Sopranos_ call another, who was being a bit cowardly, 'little miss pissypants'.

Comment: Honourable mention: [bananapants](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bananapants).

Comment: @Tuffy I'd have no idea what "check shorts" are

Comment: @KateBunting  re: "Ski pants" - really, that name is only borrowed from the USA - it's not a first-class UK term.

Comment: @MikeB - Yes, I realise that, but I was just trying to show that _pants_ doesn't always and exclusively mean underwear to a BrE speaker.

Comment: As a UK speaker it never occurred to me until now that this might be an Americanism - the expressions are in common use in the UK. (As ThaRobster's answer says, I always understood the 'pants' part to mean underwear, and it seems to make just as much sense that way.)

Comment: @ Kirk   'Check' describes "a pattern of squares in two or more colours'.  In British English, 'shorts' refer to short men's trousers (US 'pants') worn over the 'pants' (British underpants), where US 'shorts' refer refer to what the British call 'pants' and are worn under the trousers (which in the US are called 'pants).

Answer (score 28):

**How do such expressions as 'fancy-pants' sound to speakers in the UK?**

Native UK resident here. To answer the specific question asked as simply as possible - it sounds entirely natural. While 'pants' here refers to underwear rather than trousers, the phrase still makes sense.

Smarty-pants as an expression in the UK is still very ubiquitous and alternates like 'grumpy-pants', 'mardy-pants' (if you're in Yorkshire anyway) are generally well understood and while not part of every day speech in all cultures and walks of life, are still very well understood.

Smarty-trousers is categorically not a thing!

Comment: Although "clever clogs" is, for some reason.

Comment: And also "smart cookie", for some equally strange reason. FWIW, "clever clogs" and "smart cookie" are a bit different since "smarty pants" often has a bit of a pejorative color... conveying a bit of a sense or arrogance -- which the others don't, Certainly you can use "smarty pants" without that color, but it is certainly not uncommon. FWIW, when you want to be more explicit about the arrogance, you'd say they were "too clever by half" or "too big for their own boots". Which just shows what a rich language English is.

Comment: "fancy-pants" much less than the others IME (probably less than "mardy-pants" and I'm down south)

Comment: IME in the US, the primary meaning of “smarty pants” is the pejorative meaning @FraserOrr mentions and I’ve never heard it used to mean “smart”.

Comment: I'm glad "smart cookie" is good in the UK.  "Smart biscuit" just doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Charles: From the UK too, I think of *smartypants* as primarily sarcastic and hence (at least mildly) pejorative, while e.g. grumpy-pants is similarly pejorative already in its non-sarcastic meaning.

Answer (score 18):

I believe this family of words derives from a parallel with the original "smarty pants" much as we have a family of words derived from marathon (hackathon, jokeathon etc.) or Watergate (memogate, emailgate, partygate etc.) -athon meaning something done over a long period of time, and -gate referring to a political scandal of some sort.

The origins of *smarty pants* are described on [World Wide Words](https://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-sma2.htm) which, in summary, doesn't have clear origins, as with much slang, but has its origins is in the US in the 1930s. However, this doesn't give a specific citation. A user on [Using English](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/history-of-smarty-pants.112040/) gives a specific citation in 1941 "1941 by B. Schulenberg in What makes Sammy Run? where he uses the phrase "one of those Vassar smartypants." And a [search in Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smarty%20pants&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) gives some [from 2018](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Singers/Q3dxDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22smarty%20pants%22&pg=PT23&printsec=frontcover) "It freaked out some preacher kids, smarty pants from a Bible science class...".

From this meaning derive various words such as grumpy-pants, fancy pants, sleepy-pants etc., meaning a person with a strong propensity to the adjective. As with marathon or Watergate it is fairly acceptable to just coin a word of this form by sticking whatever adjective (or verb for marathon, or noun for Watergate) to make an implied meaning.

There isn't really any meaning to "pants" here, just as there isn't in  the -athon of Marathon or the -gate of Watergate. it is just a strange idiomatic convention. And FWIW, I was brought up in the UK but now live in the USA. Smarty-trousers is not an expression I have ever heard, though occasionally a -boots suffix has a similar usage in Britain, "bossy boots" for example. Some references on the web do suggest that "smarty boots" is used, but I have never heard that myself.

Edit: I found some other citations. [This one from 2021](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Reg_Rawlins_Psychic_Investigator_4_6/K3LwDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22smarty%20pants%22&pg=PT205&printsec=frontcover). "Jessup made a face at her. 'No smarty-pants. I didn't like it....". A few more [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Riding_Fence/6ngYEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22smarty%20pants%22&pg=PT18&printsec=frontcover) (2018, orig. published 2006), [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Riding_Fence/6ngYEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22smarty%20pants%22&pg=PT18&printsec=frontcover) (2018, orig. published 2006) and [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dr_Brown_Is_Missing/pg_6DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22smarty%20pants%22&pg=PA92&printsec=frontcover) (2020).

Comment: The term for this sort of reasonably productive patterning on an original template (eg red is the new black [_Y is the new X_] {see [orange is the new black](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334110/orange-is-the-new-black)}, _Xgate_ ... is _snowclone_.

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth, you comment really enhances my answer -- and I'd vaguely heard that term but didn't know what it meant.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that 'pants' may be an abbreviation of 'pantomime': a kind of deliberately over-the-top theatre that is traditional in UK around Christmas - saying "It's pants" about something means that it is rubbish. "Pants" as an item of clothing always sounds American to me.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n it is an interesting theory, but I don't think it'll fly. The expression's origin is clearly in the US, and pantomime does not mean that here. Here it mean theater without words rather than the traditional over the top theatre that it means in Britain.

Comment: _Pantomime_ is normally abbreviated to _panto_.

Comment: Google books dates need to be double checked, the same thing has happened to me. [Riding Fence](https://www.amazon.it/Riding-Fence-H-Holt/dp/0803498012) by AH Holt, the first of your links, (please avoid using "here" and write the source name) was published in **2006**

Comment: `"Far back as 1933"` shows a page from a book titled ["Singers” by Luis Harss](https://www.waterstones.com/book/singers/luis-harss/9781506533483) and has the words "solar panels" on the same page. That too was published in **2018/20** I'm going to stop checking now and give a downvote.

Comment: I checked.  In  the link `this article` which is a forum on Using English.com, it cites the two books that mention "smarty pants": "What makes Sammy Run" **(1941)** and “No More Meadows“ **(1953)**. The original link is here http://www.mrsmartypants.com/whois.html Those dates are accurate.

Comment: Re. _-gate_: obligatory link to [Watergategate](https://youtu.be/vB9JgxhXW5w).

Comment: @FraserOrr Why do you have to bring reality into the picture :-)

Comment: @j4nd3r53n, the OED dates "pants" = "rubbish" from 1994 (and that matches my memory).

Comment: You need to look at the front of the book to see when it was published, not what Google Books says (which is based on OCR guesswork): Google Books is a liar. You should probably do some further editing on this since the dates were so far off that your answer needs heavier revising than what I can give you. (You could really just remove those sections).

Answer (score 5):

I am a Brit (in my late 20s, from the Southeast and speaking fairly typical Standard Southern British English) and I certainly wouldn't think of these phrases as a synecdoche.

The grumpiness of a grumpypants doesn't lie in the pants, or even their trousers, *the grumpiness lies in the grumpypants themself*.

This is likely a **back-formation** from the more literally metonymous "smarty-pants" or "fancy-pants" which both take off in American English in the 1930s [[graph]](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fancy-pants%2Csmarty-pants&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3), before gradually spreading to British English in the 60s [[graph]](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fancy-pants%2Csmarty-pants&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3). In this case, it literally refers to someone with smart or fancy pants (trousers).

From there, -pants was **backformed** in the same way as -*holic* (from alcoholic), -*copter* (from helicopter), or -*athon* (from marathon). The only difference here is that -*pants* happens to also be a noun in its own right. This isn't unique though, and is also seen in -*gate* (from the Watergate [Hotel Scandal])

The parallel formation in -*boots* is used in the UK (especially with "bossy", probably for the alliteration), but again I don't think it can be called a synecdoche, or even metonymy because the bossiness is not actually a feature of the boots.

In all cases (i.e. -*pants*, -*boots*, -*holic*, -*copter*, -*athon*, -gate) these are best regarded as n**oun-forming derivational suffixes**, with -*pants* & -*boots* typically being **deadjectival** (i.e. applied to adjectives).

**Just as -*gate* does not imply any particular relation to physical gates, I don't associate adjectives formed in -*pants* to have any relation to underwear or trousers.**

Comment: I believe the claim is that the original term "smarty-pants" comes from a syecdoche. The person is smart, but the word just refers to their pants, which is a part of the whole, hence a synecdoche. Of course, all the other -pants words are then back-formations from this.

Comment: @Barmar for it to be a synecdoche "smartypants" would need to be part of the whole, not merely the pants

Comment: Tthey said "-pants was added to something as a synecdoche". The suffix is the synecdoche.

Answer (score 1):

> How do such expressions as 'fancy-pants' sound to speakers in the UK? Are they understandable in meaning but recognizable as being North American?

I don't think any British person today would have difficulty in understanding the meaning of **smarty-pants**. British people are already familiar with American expressions such as *candy*, *cookies*, *sidewalk*, *peanut butter and jelly* (UK *jam*), and *pants* meaning *trousers*.  In fact, the North American expression reminds me of a well-established taunt that I used to hear London school children hurl at each other during the 1970s.

> ## smart-arse (*smart-ass* AmE)
>
> noun [ C ] UK offensive
> someone who is always trying to seem more clever than other people in a way that is annoying:
> – *I don't want some smart-arse from the city telling me how to manage my farm.*
> <sub>source: *[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/smart-arse)*</sub>

It's my hunch that the noun *smart-arse* (1962) is derived from another American loanword whose origin dates back to **1863**

> ### [smart-alec](https://www.etymonline.com/word/smart%20aleck)
>
> also **s*mart alek***, ***smart alec***, "would-be clever person," by 1863 ["Weekly Butte Record," Oroville, Calif., May 16, 1863], of unknown origin. Barnhart suggests perhaps in reference to *Aleck* Hoag, notorious pimp, thief, and confidence man in New York City in early 1840s. But the dates don't overlap and the earliest use seems to concentrate in the U.S. West (Idaho and Nevada).
> <sub>source: etymonline</sub>

An early variant of smarty-pants was **smartpants**, unhyphenated and without the suffix *-y*, it turns up in [*Time*, volume 34](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Time/ty6fmL3-hrMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22be%20smart%20or%20a%20young%20smartpants%20who%22&dq=%22be%20smart%20or%20a%20young%20smartpants%20who%22&printsec=frontcover) in **1939**

> Nobody has decided yet whether Pinky Smith is a young liberal who happens to be smart or a young **smartpants** who finds it convenient to appear liberal. But nobody denies that he has gone far in his 30 years and promises to go much father.

In a **1935** novel, *Some We Loved* by Edward Harris Heth, the jeer appears, without speech marks, hinting that American readers were already familiar with its usage.

> …and you're so good to me, God Almighty you're good to me! I'm sorry, sir, they won't answer!’ [*Why, you smarty-pants, so you know it, do you?*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22They%20won%27t%20answer%21%20Why%2C%20you%20smarty%20pants%2C%20so%20you%20know%20it%2C%20do%20you%3F%22&biw=1123&bih=632&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1900%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1935&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AB5stBg8c0Z_qeKh9Hiq4Trm1KMOfTLS3Q%3A1691492620015&ei=DCHSZNNCgo3Fzw_2_bmYBA&ved=0ahUKEwjT-IWG9cyAAxWCRvEDHfZ-DkMQ4dUDCAk&oq=%22They%20won%27t%20answer%21%20Why%2C%20you%20smarty%20pants%2C%20so%20you%20know%20it%2C%20do%20you%3F%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIkMiVGhleSB3b24ndCBhbnN3ZXIhIFdoeSwgeW91IHNtYXJ0eSBwYW50cywgc28geW91IGtub3cgaXQsIGRvIHlvdT8iSM-qAVDfE1jelwFwAHgAkAEAmAF9oAHdD6oBBDE5LjS4AQzIAQD4AQHCAgQQIRgKiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-books) He slammed down the receiver and, sweating, suffocating from smoke, broke from his cage, his eyes blinking at the bright lights decorated with red-and-white crêpe-paper —*Ah-ha! my college, my alma mater!*–on the ceiling.

Answer (score 0):

As the "pants" in "fancypants" do not refer to actual pants, even in the originating language; it loses its connection. The usage of "pants" that doesn't refer to clothing is unusual, but relatively easy to understand when hearing it used in the appropriate context.

Once this usage of non-clothing "pants" is acknowledged by the listener, i.e. a Brit who is aware that even an American saying "fancypants" is not referring to what they call a pair of trousers; they inherently also no longer sign up to interpreting the "pants" in "fancypants" to refer to underwear in their own dialect either.

This is one of those words that are learned through encountering it in the wild more so than knowing its academic definition; and the inherent context that you tend to get when encountering things in the wild makes it very obvious that *no one* is referring to an article of clothing.

I think this would be a bigger hurdle if the Americans *were* referring to pants/trousers; because then it's not as easy to disconnect the word "pants" from its meaning.